# IIS Wordpress Not accepting connections from internet

Tags: wordpress, iis

I recently setup a wordpress website on IIS.

I configured the website and it is working on the local machine. I can browse pages and get to the wordpress admin.

[image]

I also configured IIS with the correct site binding, host name and ip address.

[image]

However from the internet I can not reach the website. It's as if the wordpress site is not listening to or IIS is not passing along traffic from the internet. And just to make sure it wasn't an issue with IIS. I setup a second website on that server that is accessible from the web. That one is working.

Any anyone has any ideas I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Try adding a basic HTML page into the IIS structure under the top level URL and browse that. Does it work? If yes, something wrong with wordpress. If not, then your DNS is probably the root cause. If you can post the IIs logs that prove the connectivity it may help

Comment: The site works on the local machine. Also from other computers on the domain. I also setup another test domain on the webserver that does work like it should. It just seems that the wordpress website is ignoring whatever settings that are in the iis manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some testing.

In this case. The wordpress site would not respond or map to the correct domain name on the main ip address of the server.

After adding a second IP address on the nic card and mapping that in IIS the website worked properly.

It was a very strange situation. It should of just worked on the main IP. But it didn't. shrug.